# Clients in PPTP VPN can ping each other, but cannot establish a TCP connection between them

Tags: networking, vpn, pptp

I followed this [guide](https://github.com/bluemoon93/UsefulPi/tree/master/VPN) to establish a PPTP VPN connection on my Raspberry Pi. I have a laptop (192.168.0.219) and a desktop (192.168.0.177) on my WAN, and the desktop is running a server application on port 7913:

```
desktop $ netstat -n -p tcp -a
  TCP    0.0.0.0:7913           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
```

On my laptop, this works:

```
laptop $ telnet 192.168.0.177 7913
Trying 192.168.0.177...
Connected to 192.168.0.177.
```

I connect both machines to my PPTP VPN, and the laptop gets address 192.168.1.102, and the desktop gets address 192.168.1.100. Both machines can ping each other, but this no longer works.

```
laptop $ telnet 192.168.1.100 7913
Trying 192.168.1.100...
```

`netcat` on my desktop shows things working:

```
desktop $ nc.exe -z -v 192.168.1.100 7900-7920
DESKTOP [192.168.1.100] 7913 (?) open
```

But on my laptop, nothing. What can be happening? Is it some missing `iptables` rule? Or how can I debug this?